# Search a column and delete another row if phrase found VBA

Tags: vba, excel, search

I have Column A and what I'm looking to do is search for a phrase, say "test" and then if this phrase is found delete 2 rows after that.

I can see how to delete a row if the phrase is found in that row but not how to delete another row.

Comment: show us what have you tried so far, please.

Comment: you are probably looking for the Offset method of the range object found. E.g. `ws.Range(foundRange.Offset(1,0), foundRange.Offset(2,0)).EntireRow.Delete`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
Public Sub DeleteRowsIfFound()
    Dim originCell As Range, numberOfRowsToDelete As Integer
    Dim blankCellLimit As Integer, numberOfBlankCells As Integer
    Dim label As String, index As Long, n As Integer

    Set originCell = Me.Range("A1")
    blankCellLimit = 5
    numberOfRowsToDelete = 2
    index = 0
    label = "test"

    Do
        If originCell.Offset(index, 0).Value = label Then
            For n = 0 To numberOfRowsToDelete - 1
                originCell.Offset(index + 1, 0).EntireRow.Delete
            Next
        ElseIf originCell.Offset(index, 0).Value = "" Then
            numberOfBlankCells = numberOfBlankCells + 1
        End If

        index = index + 1
    Loop While numberOfBlankCells < blankCellLimit
End Sub
```

This starts searching down column A starting at cell A1, and if it finds a cell with the value "test" then it will delete the next two rows following it.

Comment: This is perfect! I was just looking into the Offset method due to Cor_Blimey commenting above about it but you've completely cleared everything up! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad it was useful for you.  Just a warning that it will delete a row that is marked with "test" in column A if it is within two rows of another "test" marker.

Comment: Yeah that's totally fine. Just a quick question - I modified the code to only delete the next row down for another process I need to do and for some reason it now says "Excel cannot complete this task with available resources..." followed by "1004" Delete method of Range class failed". Know any reason why that'd be? It highlights - originCell.Offset(index + 1, 0).EntireRow.Delete as the problem

Comment: Not sure.  I just modified the code to remove only a single line and had no errors.  Did you copy/paste the code onto the worksheet object with the list?  This most likely would not work if copied into a code module.  You might try closing Excel and re-opening it (which may or may not help).